# How to make Random sound when button click?

Tags: java, android, button, random, soundpool

So i have 4 sound here, i was use SoundPool

```
     sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.aww, 1);
     sound2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.arh, 1);
     sound3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.agg, 1);
     sound4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.uhh, 1);
```

so i wonder how to make button choose random sound :

```
    click= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bm);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View click){             
             //choose one of four sound to play   
            }
        });
}
```

Anyone have some Idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would put all the references into an array, generate a random index and play the sound on said index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store soundIDs in an array and select one of them randomly with Random class of Java.

```
int[] sound = new int[4];
sound[0] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.aww, 1);
sound[1] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.arh, 1);
sound[2] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.agg, 1);
sound[3] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.uhh, 1);

Random random = new Random();

click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View click) {
        //choose one of four sound to play
        soundPool.play(sound[random.nextInt(4)], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a reference to each of the sounds in an array? Then you can generate a random number between 0 and array.length-1 and play that sound.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have N sound clips

```
 int[] sounds={sound1, sound2,.........., soundN};
```

get them play randomly on click of button

```
 Random r = new Random();
 int start = 0;
 int end = N;
 int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start) + start; 
 player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[playRandom]);
 player.start();
```