# How to play a random sound using SoundPool?

Tags: java, android, audio, playback, soundpool

[How to make Random sound when button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960918/how-to-make-random-sound-when-button-click)

I'm quite new to the programming world and I had previously checked the above link to try and use it as a reference to play a random sound. I'm using SoundPool since I understand that it's better at playing short clips than MediaPlayer. I have a total of four sounds.

When I run my app, I get an error saying that unfortunately it has stopped.

Any ideas on what could be possibly wrong?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class actibida extends AppCompatActivity {
SoundPool soundPool;
Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actibida);

    final int[] sound = new int[4];
    sound[0] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.el, 1);
    sound[1] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.guau, 1);
    sound[2] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.miau, 1);
    sound[3] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.quack, 1);

    final Random r = new Random();

    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {
            soundPool.play(sound[r.nextInt(4)], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually created an instance of SoundPool to work with.  Before you call soundPool.load, you will have to use [the SoundPool constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool%28int,%20int,%20int%29) (or the [Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html) API) to create an instance that defines some properties of the SoundPool.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was quite a dumb mistake. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please don't forget to accept this answer as the correct one.